# How to use map! in ruby to determine if number is in a range

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to get map! to substitute out values if they're not in range but I can't get the range to work.

```
array[0].map! { |x| x != (2..8) ? "foo" : x}
```

I'm working with a 2d array that will have numbers and I need to replace anything not in range within the first array with another static value so it can be later sorted out.

The array I'm working on will look something like this

```
[ "bar", "2", "3", "baz"]
```

Which needs to be converted to look like

```
[ "foo", "2", "3", "foo" ]
```

Comment: A range is always truthy. It works in a case statement because the cases statement uses a `===` on each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given input array, you have strings as elements of your array.  You need to convert the elements to `numeric` before it can be compared with range.  There are few methods that helps to check whether a number is part of a range or not:  [`Range#cover?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), [`Range#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) and [`Range#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Here is one way to do this:

```
array[0].map! { |x| (2..8) === x.to_i ? x : "foo"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the existence of an element in an Array like this:

```
(2..8).include? 1 => false
```